# np.unravel_index very slow

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Say I have an image of resolution H x W x 3 (img) and I have a copy of this image downsampled to resolution H' x W' x 3 (resized_img). Now, lets say I want to find the maximum value index in the image, one way to do this is

```
ind=np.unravel_index(np.argmax(img,axis=None),img.shape)
```

but if the resolution is larger, then this method is slow. On the other hand, I could find the max index on the resized img

```
img_resized=np.unravel(np.argmax(resized_img,axis=None),resized_img.shape)
```

Now, if I want the corresponding index in the original image do I just multiply by a scale factor or how do I do this?

If H=W and H'=W' then I could believe all I need to do is let

```
scale_factor=H/H'=W/W'
```

and

```
ind=resized_ind * scale_factor
```

but I am not sure if this is correct and how to treat the case when $H \neq W$.

Comment: `unravel_indes` speed does not vary much with `img.shape`.  It's a relatively simple calculation using the `shape` values.  `argmax` though will be slower when `img` is larger.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there a way for me to get the desired result by multiplying the output index (x_max,y_max) * ( H/H' . W/W')?

Comment: Experiment with some small dimensions.  Ravel/unravel is not an exotic calculation.  Scaling should be easy as well, but watch out for floats and rounding issues.

Comment: @hpaulj My initial input images are 1080x1620 resolution so I would imagine np.unravel takes close to a second where if you had a 256x256 resolution and multiplied by a factor it would be significantly less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

``ravel/unravel do not change the array; they just calculate new indices based on the shape.

Consider a simple 3d array:

```
In [63]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [64]: arr
Out[64]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

A point in that array with a tuple of indices:

```
In [65]: arr[0,1,2]
Out[65]: 6
```

The ravel and unravel:

```
In [66]: np.ravel_multi_index([0,1,2],arr.shape)
Out[66]: 6
In [67]: np.unravel_index(6, arr.shape)
Out[67]: (0, 1, 2)
```

There is a `ravel` method, but that is just a `reshape`, and thus a `view` (at least without changes in `order` etc):

```
In [69]: arr.ravel()
Out[69]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

The `ravel_multi_index` calculation is just:

```
In [70]: 2 + 4*1 + 12*0
Out[70]: 6
```

while `unravel` is some sort of reverse.  I won't get into the details but it probably uses some sort of modulus.

---

Another way to approach this is to compare the run times for two different shapes:

```
In [71]: np.unravel_index(1000, (1080,1620,3))
Out[71]: (0, 333, 1)
In [72]: np.unravel_index(1000, (256,256,3))
Out[72]: (1, 77, 1)
In [73]: timeit np.unravel_index(1000, (1080,1620,3))
5.14 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [74]: timeit np.unravel_index(1000, (256,256,3))
4.84 µs ± 29.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The run time is roughly the same for the two shapes (they overlap within the ± factors.)